# How do 3 different gen kVA ratings Service Load (maximum), Service Load (continuous), and "Motor Starting kVA (Max.) relate to the nameplate value

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, generator

I'm reading an engine generator parameter schedule that has three different kVA values listed. The standby generators have "Service Load (maximum)", "Service Load (continuous)", and "Motor Starting kVA (Max.)" values called out. Gen 1 (in the plans) is a 100 kW gen (0.8 PF, 125 kVA). Gen 2 is an 800 kW (0.8 PF, 1000kVA from plans). Below are the corresponding values found in the generator parameter schedule.

1. "Service Load (maximum)"      Gen 1 150kVA, Gen 2 1000kVA
2. "Service Load (continuous)"   Gen 1 120kVA, Gen 2 500kVA
3. "Motor Starting kVA (Max.)"   Gen 1 125kVA, Gen 2 1000kVA

I need to check these values for consistency with the plans. Isn’t the motor starting to be typically greater than the maximum service load? Which one of these values relates to the nameplate value depicted in the plans?

Example spec below
https://www.wbdg.org/FFC/DOD/UFGS/UFGS%2026%2032%2015.00.pdf

Comment: https://www.cat.com/en_US/by-industry/electric-power/Articles/White-papers/demystifying-generator-set-ratings.html.

Comment: https://www.iso.org/standard/68539.html

Comment: https://www.cummins.com/sites/default/files/2018-08/201707%20PowerHour_Understanding%20ISO%208528%20GeneratorSetRatings.pdf

Comment: This is a genref question. What reasearch did you do befor coming here?

Comment: Page 24 & 25 deal with your issue.